# Line chart via Elychart with square points insteat of dot

Tags: javascript, linechart

I look a javascript library for  creating a simple line charts.
Is it possible to create something like this via Elychart?

[image]

I read [documentation](http://elycharts.com/api) but did not find description of dot's properties.
Lots of examples describe only next properies of dot:

```
 dot: true,
 dotProps: {
      stroke: "white",
      "stroke-width": 2
    }
```

Now I have next [simple prototype.](http://jsfiddle.net/tarasp/q49zb5fb/)

Is it possible replace dots with squares?
I try to use Elychart because these charts look fine  by older versions of IE.

Thanks.

**Edited**: look like [google's chart library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points) has such feature(pointShape option for dot).

Could you give me references to library which could be used  for line-charts?

**Edited 2:** I cannot use  google chart  because  it is not possible [to use this chart library offline.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq?csw=1#offline)
Maybe could someone recommend me other library which works offline ?

Comment: Leaving as a comment, as this is technically a recommendation. Quite a few mainstream JS charting libraries are available offline, offer custom markers, and work well in legacy browsers. http://www.amcharts.com, http://www.zingchart.com, http://www.highcharts.com are a few. In the future, head over to softwarerecs stack exchange for recommendations, just make sure you follow the posting guidelines. Good luck!

Comment: @Chlorination Thanks for comments. These libraries are commercial. For now I try to find some open source library. That's why I cannot use them now.

Comment: Actually, although they do all have options for licensing, all three of those libraries are available to use for free with a small watermark. Highcharts is open source if that is an absolute requirement.

Comment: @Chlorination  These libraries really have nice functionality. I checked them. But clean licence is important in my case. For now I will try to use chart.js and make something like [in this example](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/527)